# ubuntu 11.10 readline error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting a problem while running my project in ubuntu 11.10.
/home/kranthi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/readline.so: libreadline.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/kranthi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/readline.so (LoadError)

this is the error.can anyone help me in solving this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `readline` lib. I don't have a linux install close by, but something like `sudo apt-get install libreadline` should solve your problem. Maybe I got the name of the package wrong, don't hesitate to make a quick search

**EDIT** : what about `rvm pkg install readline`?

Answer (score 3):

On some Linux Distributions you have the option to install a special libreadline version for ruby. I solved my Problem on an Ubuntu Box.

For Ubuntu or Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-ruby
```

or

```
sudo aptitude install libreadline-ruby
```